# IntelliJ cannot resolve com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.PacketTooBigException

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, exception, intellij-idea

I have `mysql-connector-java` added as dependency, but I cannot use the `PacketTooBigException` inside my code. It says 'not able to resolve' .

I am writing some jdbc template based update logic, where I wish to capture instance of `PacketTooBigException` and retry with a smaller batch.

[image: cannot resolve exception class]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found what was causing the error: I had `runtime` scope for the maven dependency. Removing it solved my problem.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope> <-- this caused the problem
        </dependency>
```